# Expected a type & Failed to import bridging header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I'm working on a project that contains Swift and Objective_C code, it works without any problem until i was trying to import a ".h" class in my "Bridging-Header" file:

- **Expected a type** : in the class that i was trying to import it
- **Failed to import bridging header** '/Users/sysadmin/Desktop/Application /Classes/UI/Application-Bridging-Header.h'

however when i have imported an other class in Bridging Header that works without problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 3 ways to import objective c file in Swift project.

1. `#import "FileName.h"`
2. `#import <FolderName/FileName.h>`
3. `@import PackageName;` like `@import Alamofire;`

Comment: Welcome Bro. if My solution is work for you then mark Green so else user get guid.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing your class like

```
#import "classname.h" if this fails try
#import `<classname/classname.h>`
```

Remember to clean and then run after you make a change.
Again if it fails check whether you have added the class to your target