# Xcode : Bridging header not recognising imports

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header, objc-bridging-header

I have a project contains objective C code and I want to implement new features using Swift so I created Bridging header and added it to the build paths, the problem now is when I add #import "xx" to the Bridging header #import is not recognized and when I add it manually by copying and pasting like #import "MBProgressHUD.h", then i try to view the source code I get "?" although when I import the same library in any other .h or .m file it works.
Note: I know that "MBProgressHUD" works with swift, it was just for reference.

Appreciating any support and thanks in advance

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496055/getting-file-not-found-in-bridging-header-when-importing-objective-c-framework

Comment: Thanks but non of them worked except for the accepted answers where i don't have or can not find those fields

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected a type & Failed to import bridging header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44199616/expected-a-type-failed-to-import-bridging-header)

Comment: @Kiran Sarvaiya Not like my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do like this 
1、drag the `MBProgressHUD` into your project
2、[you can create an `OC` class first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBc8H.png)
, which will remind if you create `yourProject-Bridging-Header.h`, choose yes 
3、[import `#import "MBProgressHUD.h"` in the `-Bridging-Header.h`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YYzE.png)，And then compile the project 
4、[use it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DVDl.jpg)

Comment: I already did that but still not working, the import command it self is not auto completed

Comment: do you have created `-Bridging-Header.h` in your project ? if true, you must set ( `Build Settings - Swift Compiler - Objective-C Bridging Header` ) to relative path,

Comment: Since you did it all.  have you compiled your project, than do `above 4` ,If no code is prompted, you need type the code by yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much